# Jsoup how to remove tr does not contain specific text?

Tags: android, parsing, jsoup

I want to do a filter for my timetable. How i do is trying to remove the tr does not contain my class, then i can remain what i need. But i don't how to use :not and :contain together. Anyone help? or suggest other idea?

```
tableRow = filterUse.select("tr:not(:contain("+lecture+"):contains("+lab+"):contains("+tutorial+"))").remove();
```

error logcat:

```
12-03 18:15:41.853: E/AndroidRuntime(2324): Caused by: org.jsoup.select.Selector$SelectorParseException: Could not parse query ':contain(L-2):contains(LAB-3):contains(T-3)': unexpected token at ':contain(L-2):contains(LAB-3):contains(T-3)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `:matches(regex)` or `:matchesOwn(regex)`.

```
tableRow = filterUse.select("tr:matches((?is)" + lecture + "|" + lab + "|" + tutorial + ")").remove;
```